# Premiere Pro CS6 Won't Install on Windows 10

Tags: premiere, software, cs6

[image] I wanna to create professional videos for upload to YouTube at 1080p, but after installing Windows 10 I can't install Premiere Pro CS6.  I get warning icons and the option to install Premiere is greyed out.  How can I get around this error and get Premiere to install?

Comment: Are the checkboxes greyed out? What happens if you click or hover over the warning "!" icons?

Comment: How much space do you have on the hard drive?  It looks like the warnings might be telling you that there isn't enough space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on info revealed in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29340146#29340146):

> I trying to install that on windows 10 32 bit . Is it a problem ?

the answer is that since version CS5, Premiere Pro is 64-bit only and can't be installed on a 32-bit OS.